# How to handle Non standard Apdu?

Tags: java, smartcard, javacard, apdu

I've developed Java applet for old existing system. And I found the non ISO7816 apdu standard.
Cla:0x80
Ins :0xFA
When I processed this command the applet crashed. Is there any way to handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

The only non-standard aspect is, that ISO 7816 does not **define** this command. Otherwise it surely is compliant with the standard in the sense that it does not violate it.

So your app seems at fault by incorrectly handling that scenario (like issuing `SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED` for all commands not recognized).

Comment: Just to add to this response, if you don't have much experience with writing applets, when dealing with bytes in Java take good care about type casting. It's easy to make a mistake with values that have most significant bit set. You might stare for a while at (almost) perfectly good code until you realize it. As for the rest, you should probably show us some code if we are to help you